# Перебор Map со счетчиком итераций

Tags: javascript

Есть экземпляр Map, например

```
let rec = new Map([
  ["1", Buffer.from('a', 'hex')],
  ["2", Buffer.from('b', 'hex')],
]);
```

Можно ли его перебрать с помощью `forEach` так же, как с обычным одномерным массивом? Т.е., мне нужно в одном участке кода использовать "1", а в другом Buffer.from('b', 'hex')
Это возможно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать так:

```
let rec = new Map([
  ["1", Buffer.from('a', 'hex')],
  ["2", Buffer.from('b', 'hex')],
]), index = 1;
```

Первый способ:

```
rec.forEach((key, value) => {
   console.log(index + ' - ' + key + ' = ' + value);
   ++index;
});
```

Второй способ:

```
for (var [key, value] of rec.entries()) {
  console.log(index + ' - ' + key + ' = ' + value);
  ++index;
}
```

Работать будет и без `.entries()` тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью IIFE (счетчик в аргументе, и его инкремент "вручную"):

```js
let rec = new Map([
  ['1', 'First value'],
  ['2', 'Second value'],
]);

(idx => rec.forEach((val, key) => {        // idx - счетчик
  console.log(idx++, ':', val);            // постинкремент на каждой итерации 
}))(0);                                    // 0 - начальное значение счетчика
```

Или через временный массив:

```
[...rec.entries()].forEach(([val, key], idx) => /*...*/);
```

Оба этих способа характерны тем что не требуют объявления внешней переменной для значения счетчика.
Второй способ кушает память - его желательно использовать только с небольшими словарями.